# Create Rarfiles with old style?

Tags: linux, rar

I need a solution to create Rarfiles with old style, like *.r00 ...
since version 5 it does not work with `-vn switch is not supported for RAR 5.x archive format.` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `rar` command's help page:

> **vn**
>   Use the old style volume naming scheme

Thus, if you want to create volumes with the old naming scheme you need to use the following:

```
rar a -vn -v<volume size> archive [files ...]
```

The `-vn` switch is not working on version 5.+, but you can force using version 4 with the `-ma4` switch:

```
rar a -ma4 -vn -v<volume size> archive [files ...]
```

#### Related:

- [Switch -VN - use the old style volume naming scheme](https://www.winrar-france.fr/winrar_instructions_for_use/source/html/HELPSwVN.htm)
- [Switch -MA[4|5] - specify a version of archiving format](https://www.winrar-france.fr/winrar_instructions_for_use/source/html/HELPSwMA.htm)

Comment: it was only working till version 5.0!

Comment: @loolery, yes indeed, I misread the question. Answer corrected.

Comment: it works, thx :)